# Haskell: Efficient accumulator

Tags: haskell, accumulator

What is the best way to map across a list, using the result of each map as you go along, when your result is of a different type to the list.

for example

```
f :: Int -> Int -> String -> String

l = [1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to have something that walks along the list l and does:

`f 1 2 [] = result1 => f 2 3 result1 = result2 => f 3 4 result3  ==> return result3.`

I can sort of get this to work with a an accumulator, but it seems rather cumbersome. Is there a standard way to do this... or is this something for Monads??

Thanks!

NB the function above is just for illustration.

Comment: more generally you could use a sliding window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a fold left over the pairs in the input list:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
f = undefined

accum :: [Int] -> String
accum xs = foldl (flip . uncurry $ f) "" $ zip xs (drop 1 xs)
```

You probably want to use `Data.List.foldl'` instead of `foldl`, but this is an answer that works with just Prelude.

Comment: That's no reason to be scared of `foldl'`!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a job for `fold`:

```
func f l = foldl (\s (x, y) -> f x y s) "" (zip l (tail l))

-- just some placeholder function
f :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
f x y s = s ++ " " ++ show(x) ++ " " ++ show(y)

l = [1,2,3,4]

main = print $ func f l
```

prints:

```
" 1 2 2 3 3 4"
```

(if you can change the signature of `f`, you can get rid of the ugly lambda that rearranges arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, rather than zipping, you could pass along the previous element inside the fold's accumulator. For example:

```hs
l = [1,2,3,4]
f x y = (x,y)
g b@(accum,prev) a = (accum ++ [f prev a],a)

main = print (foldl g ([],head l) (tail l))
```

Output:

```
([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],4)
```